# Detecting gaps and creating missing rows of timeperiods

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**The setup:**

I have a table with the following columns:

- tokenname
- overall_date_start = 01.01.2020
- overall_date_end = 12.02.2021
- sub_date_start = *
- sub_date_end = *

For each tokenname I have one "overall"/general timeperiod (e.g. 01.01.2020 - 31.12.2020) and multiple rows per tokenname, each with a specific sub-timeperiod. As an example:

- row 1 - sub_date_start = **01.01.2020**; sub_date_end = 28.04.2020
- row 2 - sub_date_start = 29.04.2020; sub_date_end = 01.08.2020
- row 3 - sub_date_start = 02.08.2020; sub_date_end = **12.02.2021**

The sub-timeperiods are supposed to be continuous and are supposed to start and end with the same dates as the overall/general timeperiod. There is no overlap between the timeperiods.

**The problem:**

Some of the tokens are missing some rows/sub-timeperiods. For instance, the first, some in the middle or the last sub-timeperiod might be missing.

I have been racking my brain how to:

1. identify the gaps
2. fill them

I thought about using window functions to detect if there is a gap, but I got stuck on how to go from there to create the missing rows with the timeperiods.

```
     CASE 
     WHEN -- First entry of the token art
        LAG(sub_date_end ,1) OVER (   
            PARTITION BY token
            ORDER BY     token, sub_date_start ASC
        ) IS NULL  -- no previous one == first row.
        THEN 
                  CASE -- check gap between row and overall
                    WHEN sub_date_start != overall_date_start 
                    THEN 'gap detected between start and first row'
                  ELSE '' -- no gap 
                 END 
     WHEN -- Gap between row's start and previous row's end
            LAG(sub_date_end ,1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY token
            ORDER BY     token, sub_date_start ASC
            ) != sub_date_start -1  
           THEN 'gap detected between this and the previous one'
    ELSE '' -- no gap

    END AS gaps_between_rows
```

The pseudo code explained:

- I use a windowfunction to access the previous row's end.
- If there is no previous row, it must be the first row => if the row's start and overall start don't match, there is a gap.
- If there is an end => if the previous row's end is not preceding the current row's start, there is a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just completing the ideas you listed.

This dummy data has 4 missing records - including the first and last record.

`COALESCE` can be used to handle if the first record is missing as `LAG` will result in `NULL`. The last record needs to be handled separately.

```
WITH dummy_data AS (
  -- Missing 2019-08-01 to 2019-12-31
  SELECT 1 AS token, '2019-08-01' AS overall_date_start, '2021-05-01'::DATE AS overall_date_end, '2020-01-01'::DATE AS sub_date_start, '2020-04-28'::DATE AS sub_date_end
  UNION SELECT 1, '2019-08-01'::DATE, '2021-05-01'::DATE, '2020-04-29'::DATE, '2020-08-01'::DATE
  -- Missing 2020-08-02 to 2020-09-01
  UNION SELECT 1, '2019-08-01'::DATE, '2021-05-01'::DATE, '2020-09-02'::DATE, '2020-10-01'::DATE
  -- Missing 2020-10-02 to 2020-11-01
  UNION SELECT 1, '2019-08-01'::DATE, '2021-05-01'::DATE, '2020-11-02'::DATE, '2021-02-12'::DATE
  -- Missing  2021-02-13 to 2021-05-01
),
missing_last AS (
  SELECT
    token,
    overall_date_start,
    overall_date_end,
    
    MAX(sub_date_end) + 1 AS new_sub_date_start,
    overall_date_end AS new_sub_date_end,
    new_sub_date_start < overall_date_end AS is_missing
  FROM dummy_data
  GROUP BY token, overall_date_start, overall_date_end
),
missing_other AS (
  SELECT
    token,
    overall_date_start,
    overall_date_end,
    
    COALESCE(
      LAG(sub_date_end, 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY token
        ORDER BY token, sub_date_start
      ) + 1,
      overall_date_start
    ) AS new_sub_date_start,
    sub_date_start - 1 AS new_sub_date_end,
    
    new_sub_date_start != sub_date_start AS is_missing
  FROM dummy_data
),
missing_all AS (
  SELECT * FROM missing_last
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM missing_other
)
SELECT
  token,
  overall_date_start,
  overall_date_end,
  new_sub_date_start AS sub_date_start,
  new_sub_date_end AS sub_date_end
FROM missing_all
WHERE is_missing
ORDER BY sub_date_start
```

```
-- token    overall_date_start  overall_date_end  sub_date_start  sub_date_end
--     1            2019-08-01        2021-05-01      2019-08-01    2020-12-31
--     1            2019-08-01        2021-05-01      2020-08-02    2020-09-01
--     1            2019-08-01        2021-05-01      2020-10-02    2020-11-01  
--     1            2019-08-01        2021-05-01      2021-02-13    2021-05-01
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have to work myself through the code to understand it fully, but the results speak for themselves :)

Comment: This is very elegant! I am a bit confused by the where clause though ->  `WHERE sub_date_start != overall_date_start `  why do you filter out the first sub-period (if there exists one)?

Comment: `missing_other` goes through each record and finds the start and end date for the record that should come _before_ it. `WHERE sub_date_start != overall_date_start` prevents us from trying to get info about the record prior to the start (which would be invalid).

Comment: But if we filter out the first entry, don't we automatically find a "is_missing" for the second entry afterwards? Example: If I add the starting timeperiod for `2019-08-01 to 2019-12-31` to the dummy_data, I get that row twice in the result -> once in missing, once in the dummy_data.

Comment: Ah you're right - that `WHERE` should be removed. Having the invalid record before the first period actually won't matter because it will have `is_missing` as `FALSE` and won't be included.